# M2 NVME not recognized as such - very bad performance

Tags: drivers, ssd, disk, storage, nvme

I have two M2 SSDs installed.
One from **Western Digital (WD)** and one from **Samsung**.
I tested the speed with hdparm and dd. The WD disk is very slow with read and write between 30-150 MB/s. So there must be something wrong. Already swapped the slots on the board and checked for a firmware update. Same problem.

I saw using "lsblk" that the Samsung is shown as "nvme" while the WD is shown as "/dev/sda". Does someone have an idea how to debug this? Is the WD disk falsely recognized as a "normal" disk?
And "lsh" shows some differences too.

WD (listed under scsi):

```
     *-scsi:0
      Physische ID: d
      Logischer Name: scsi1
      Fähigkeiten: emulated
    *-disk
         Beschreibung: ATA Disk
         Produkt: WDC  WDS500G2B0B
         Hersteller: Western Digital
         Physische ID: 0.0.0
         Bus-Informationen: scsi@1:0.0.0
         Logischer Name: /dev/sda
         Version: 20WD
         Seriennummer: <omitted>
         Größe: 465GiB (500GB)
         Fähigkeiten: partitioned partitioned:dos
         Konfiguration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=aef2cc84
```

Samsung (listed under pci):

```
           *-storage
            Beschreibung: Non-Volatile memory controller
            Produkt: NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
            Hersteller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
            Physische ID: 0
            Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:02:00.0
            Version: 00
            Breite: 64 bits
            Takt: 33MHz
            Fähigkeiten: storage pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
            Konfiguration: driver=nvme latency=0
            Ressourcen: irq:16 memory:ed100000-ed103fff
          *-nvme0
               Beschreibung: NVMe device
               Produkt: SAMSUNG MZVLB256HAHQ-000H1
               Physische ID: 0
               Logischer Name: /dev/nvme0
               Version: EXD70H1Q
               Seriennummer: <ommitted>
               Konfiguration: nqn=nqn.2014.08.org.nvmexpress:144d144dS425NX0M185485      SAMSUNG MZVLB256HAHQ-000H1 state=live
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: Made more tests. Seems the SSD has a problem. Will return.

Comment: This is an English language site, so please change your system language before running commands with outputs you will need to post here as details. `/dev/sdX#` and `/dev/nvme#` are mount points. They have nothing to do with whether a drive is NVMe or any other device specification

Comment: The WD storage device [uses a SATA interface](https://www.westerndigital.com/products/internal-drives/wd-blue-sata-2-5-ssd#WDS250G2B0A) rather than NMVe, so the `/dev/sdX` assignment is correct. That said, throughput is expected to be about 500MB/sec for sustained operations 